# After selecting a row in data table it goes to top

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jquery datatable of version 1.9. When I am selecting a row on the table, the datatable goes to top. so I have to scroll down again to select any other row. Is there a way I can stop this behavior?

I have got following code to catch the selected row event where I am updating an invisible column value for that row.

```
$(data_table).on('click', 'tr', function(e) {

    data_table.fnUpdate(1, data_table.fnGetPosition(this), 9);
});
```

When I am not using **fnUpdate** the data table is not going to top and works as expected.

I tried with **preventDefault()** or **stopPropagation()** but didn't work.

Comment: You should provide your code and demo (for example, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)).

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and solution in the [this link](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8845/fnupdate-when-run-while-on-a-page-other-than-1-of-a-multi-page-table-causes-the-page-to-reset-back-1). I am writing the answer for others.

So the problem is that **fnUpdate** takes a 4th parameter which represents whether to redraw the table or not. The default value is **true** which redraws the data table after update. We can make the 4th parameter **false** to stop the redrawing behavior. The api reference for [fnUpdate](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnUpdate) explains this parameter.

So I changed the code as below and it worked.

```
$(data_table).on('click', 'tr', function(e) {

    data_table.fnUpdate(1, data_table.fnGetPosition(this), 9, false);
});
```